# C# DataGridView, show columns that only have data

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using a datagridview to mirror my sql table using linq so:

```
var listOfCarRecords = dataGridView1.DataSource = record.Select(x => Mapper.Map<Cars>(x)).ToList();
```

This works fine.

However my sql table has 60 columns of which only a few are ever contain data, there are few occassions when all contain data.

So how can I show only columns with data in my datagridview?

I tried setting `autogeneratecolumns = false`but it did not work.

whats the simplest way to do this please?

thank you

Comment: How do you know column has data or not? What do you mean by it has data? Btw you can set `AutoGenerateColumns = false` and manually add columns.

Comment: I can see in my actual sql table only some columns have data. I tried setting autogeneratecolumns = false but it did not work.

Comment: What is the type of `listOfCarRecords` ? Post the class definition of `T`

Comment: the type of listOfCarRecords is Object

Answer (score 1):

Before assigning Datatable as datasource, you can remove the columns which have null values.

```
if (table.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull("ColumnName"))) // column name having null values
   table.Columns.Remove("ColumnName");
```

and then assign it to your dataGridview

```
datagridview1.DataSource = table;
```

EDIT :

```
DataTable dataTable = record.Select(...) // Your data coming from DB

// Remove Empty Columns
if (dataTable.AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull("ColumnName"))) // column name having null values
   dataTable.Columns.Remove("ColumnName");


List<Cars> listOfCarRecords = dataTable.ToCollection<Cars>;
dataGridView1.DataSource = listOfCarRecords;


// ToCollection is an extension methods for converting generic class to List
public static List<T> ToCollection<T>(this DataTable sourceDatatable)
{
    var lst = new List<T>();

    Type tClass = typeof(T);
    PropertyInfo[] pClass = tClass.GetProperties();
    List<DataColumn> dc = sourceDatatable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList();

   foreach (DataRow item in sourceDatatable.Rows)
   {
     var genericObject = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(tClass);
     foreach (PropertyInfo pc in pClass)
     {
        DataColumn d = dc.Find(c => c.ColumnName == pc.Name);
        if (d != null)
           pc.SetValue(genericObject, item[pc.Name], null);
     }
     lst.Add(genericObject);
  }
  return lst;
}
```

Comment: can you give me an example of what you mean using my own code:   var listOfCarRecords = dataGridView1.DataSource = record.Select(x => Mapper.Map<Cars>(x)).ToList();     thank you

Comment: It seems you are using AutoMapper for mapping your class to List. I have never used it but I have updated my answer to your requirements. I am using a extension methods for converting DataTable to List of classes

Comment: thanks for your efforts but is there a simpler way??